# Dúvida sobre Map/javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou com uma dúvida que é a seguinte:
Preciso de usar a função Map para trocar os valores dos objetos como por exemplo:
Start([{name:rui, sex:"m" ; name:Ana, sex:"f"}])
Como é que eu troco o sexo das pessoas, dizer que o Rui é f e a Ana é m? [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Podes explicar melhor a lógica? tens sempre 2 pessoas que trocam entre sí? ou como sabes para que valor mudar?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Eu só tenho de trocar o valor do sexo da pessoa, inverter o que tenho dentro do array. Dizer que o rapaz é feminino e a rapariga masculino.

Answer (score 4):

O teu ponto de partida é uma Array: `[{name: 'Rui', sex: "m"}, {name: 'Ana', sex: "f"}];`. O `.map()` percorre cada elemento (2 neste exemplo) e dispõe o objeto iterado. Depois só precisas de lógica para trocar o valor...

```js
const arr = [{
  name: 'Rui',
  sex: "m"
}, {
  name: 'Ana',
  sex: "f"
}];
const invert = sex => sex === 'm' ? 'f' : 'm';
const trocado = arr.map(obj => {
  return {
    ...obj,
    sex: invert(obj.sex)
  }
});

console.log(trocado);
```